# appengine loading wrong cache.js file

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

Can anyone help me?

I have a customer who is struggling to load their version of my software when they are on a 4G connection. It loads OK for them over WiFi and it loads find for ME on a 4G connection... looking at the logs it appears that when she was loading on 4G it appears to be loading a different cache.js file from me (see attached screenshot)

The failing one appears to try to load

```
/2461D59D186081A970D99393BB2ABCEF.cache.js
```

and the one that works (for me) is

```
/diarybooker/2461D59D186081A970D99393BB2ABCEF.cache.js
```

I am hoping someone might be able to enlighten me as to why appengine might be loading in different ways? and how to get it to do it right? Or even if this is actually the problem?!

[image: screenshot of the logs]

Comment: This is a url issue.  Somewhere, the app is pointing to the wrong url, without the `/diarybooker`.  The developer needs to check those urls.

Comment: Odd that it seems to work on the same phone then when you switch between WiFi and 3G (and only 3G with certain providers, O2 and TMobile in the UK) - what could be the difference as to why it changes depending on  the way it is accessed??!